# Publish two different endpoints on Kestrel for two different endpoints on ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grpc, endpoint, kestrel-http-server

I have a ASP.NET Core application that has two endpoints. One is the MVC and the other is the Grpc. I need that the kestrel publishs each endpoint on different sockets. Example: localhost:8888 (MVC) and localhost:8889 (Grpc).

I know how to publish two endpoints on Kestrel. But the problem is that it's publishing  the MVC and the gRPC on both endpoints and I don't want that. This is because I need the Grpc requests use Http2. On the other hand, I need that MVC requests use Http1

on my Statup.cs I have

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // ....
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapGrpcService<ComunicacaoService>();
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default",
                                      "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
    // ...
```

I need a way to make `endpoints.MapGrpcService<ComunicacaoService>();` be published on one socket and the `endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default","{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");` on another one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the configuration that works for me:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
           webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
           {
               options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 55001, cfg =>
               {
                   cfg.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http2;
               });

               options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 55002, cfg =>
               {
                   cfg.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http1;
               }); 
           });

           webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
       });
```

Alternatively in appsettings.json:

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Grpc": {
        "Protocols" :  "Http2",
        "Url": "http://localhost:55001"
      },
      "webApi": {
        "Protocols":  "Http1",
        "Url": "http://localhost:55002"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have yet a little question. I'm not sure how to handle this on the startup file. If I think right,  your code will publish both services on both sockets, cause that is nothing explict saying to publish one service on one port and the other on another one

Comment: From what I understand both middlewares will be present on both endpoints, just that GRPC will work only with HTTP2

Comment: I see. This is not exactly what I'm looking for but a apreciate the time to write an answer for me. Thanks man!

Comment: Have you tried instantiating, building and running two IHostBuilders (each configured individually, one for gRPC, one for MVC) and then Task.WhenAll for both?

Comment: @Stonehead Actually, no. This seems a really great idea. I'll try it out, thanks